# VIsual Web Developer Radio Button - Update Live

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I am currently trying to develop a form/website using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

In the first section is a group of radio buttons which control the subject line field. I have been able to add a RadioButtonCheckedControl attribute which will set the subject line BUT it will only work if the page is refreshed. Is there a command to live update the form?

In the ascx file there is the following:

`<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioUniform" runat="server" Text="Uniform Infringement" 
    GroupName="Reason" oncheckedchanged="RadioUniform_CheckedChanged" />`

And then in the ascx.cs file there is the following:
`protected void RadioUniform_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CommentSubject.Text = "UNIFORM INFRINGEMENT";

    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple of quick Google searches (as I've done previous nights) I found the solution. After the `OnCheckedChanged` part of the radio button code, add  `AutoPostBack="True"`.